# Submit buttons change color when hovering on non-English Stack Overflow sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, international-sites

When hovering over a submit button, on most Stack Exchange site the color changes from blue to a slightly darker shade of blue. However, on all of the four non-English Stack Overflow sites, it changes from blue to orange:

[image]

I assume this was not intended, but CSS can be a tricky beast sometimes. Tested in the latest Firefox and Safari on macOS Catalina.

Comment: Apparendly this color is also used for the `Unwatch tag` button (even if unhovered). It has turned orange too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should now be fixed. We changed how some color variables were being passed around. Our international communities should have been inheriting from Stack Overflow’s theme, but they weren't. Thanks for pointing it out!