# Ejecutar (Run) button background is the same color of the button text: white

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-snippets, international-sites

This is related to [Submit buttons change color when hovering on non-English Stack Overflow sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340412/289691), but in this case it's a problem because the button background is the same color as the button text: white

The button with the problem is the Ejectuar (Run) button of the Stack Snippet editor.

[image]

On hover the button changes

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should now be fixed. We changed how some color variables were being passed around. Our international communities should have been inheriting from Stack Overflow’s theme, but they weren't. Thanks for pointing it out!