# 'Track the next one' button barely readable when hovering

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, badge-progress

When hovering over the 'Track the next one' button in the badge tracker on your profile page, its background changes to white, which makes the light gray text hardly readable:

[image]

This seems to be another episode in the recent category 'buttons changing colors'; other ones include

- [Submit buttons change color when hovering on non-English Stack Overflow sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340412/295232)
- [Ejecutar (Run) button background is the same color of the button text: white](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340434/295232)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed with the [New responsive Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372049/295232):

[image]